# how to get yesterday date using timestamp function in pine-script

Tags: pine-script

endDate=timestamp("UTC+5:30",year,month,dayofmonth, 15,30,00)

this line gives me an output of"current year - current month - today date 15:30:00". how can I get yesterday date, so that it will keep on update yesterdays date dynamically in future also?

```
study("temp",overlay=true)
startDate=input(title="Start 
Date",type=input.time,defval=timestamp("01 Jan 2000 09:15:00 
  UTC+5:30"))
// newDay=change(time("D"))!= 0
// _year=valuewhen(newDay,year[1],0)
// _month = valuewhen(newDay, month[1], 0)
// yday = valuewhen(newDay, dayofmonth[1], 0)
// yesterdays_ts = timestamp(_year, _month, yday, 15, 30)
endDate=timestamp("UTC+5:30",year,month,dayofmonth, 15,30,00)
labelSession=input(title="Time session to 
analysis",type=input.session,defval="0915-1525")
inSession(sess)=> na(time(timeframe.period,sess + ":23456")) == false 
  and time >= startDate and time<= endDate
dayLow()=>security(syminfo.ticker,"D",low,lookahead=true)
if inSession(labelSession) and not inSession(labelSession)[1]  
label.new(bar_index,dayLow()-20,"Hello",style=label.style_label_left,textalign=text.align_left,color=#d0cec2,textcolor=color.black)
```

**if this code runs my result is**
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFn6O.png
but I don't want to print the label for the current day(i just want to print the label up to the previous day only)how can I achieve that

Answer (score 0):

```
new_day = change(time("D")) != 0

yyear = valuewhen(new_day, year[1], 0)
ymonth = valuewhen(new_day, month[1], 0)
yday = valuewhen(new_day, dayofmonth[1], 0)

yesterdays_ts = timestamp(yyear, ymonth, yday, 15, 30)
```

Comment: I tried this code, it's not working and it's not showing any error also, please go through my edited question again